# playback audio file from byte code (audio file format is CCITT A-Law)

Tags: c#, arrays, media-player, audioformat, soundplayer

I want to playback audio file from byte code. I already have byte code for audio file.
But when I playback with System.Media.SoundPlayer, I got error as "{Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files."}. My audio file format is (CCITT A-Law).
Can any one who have this knowledge share with me  pls??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard [G.711](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.711.0-200909-I/en) tells you how to convert 8 bit A-law into 16 PCM.  [Here's](http://www.soft-switch.org/spandsp-doc/src_2spandsp_2g711_8h-source.html) a code snippet

Comment: thanks for answer. but I'm finding the way with C#. any idea??

Answer (score 0):

WAV files can be encoded in many ways, usually PCM or MP3. .NET only supports PCM. Use a program to convert, this one is free (just remembed to uncheck the adware crap): http://www.nch.com.au/switch/