# Wav File asp.net c# webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, wav

How to play wav file format (A-Law, 8000 Hz, 64 Kbps, mono ) in c# asp.net web forms.

c# asp.net supports only to play wav PCM format

Comment: Take a look at this post, you will need to do some encoding / converting of the file format type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070294/playback-audio-file-from-byte-code-audio-file-format-is-ccitt-a-law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML5 to achieve this. It supports WAV files :)

Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

NOTE: Be aware that not all browsers support WAV files. You'll find more details on that page!

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely difficult to create your own a-law player, this will require deep understanding of the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) . fortunately there are tools out there such as [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to help you convert that file to the desired `.wav` format.

Here 's a function I wrote to convert files `u-law` files to wav format so I could read it

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the sound file using SoX.exe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fromFile">From file in uLaw encoding.</param>
    /// <param name="toFile">To wav file.</param>
    public bool GenerateSoundFile(string fromFile, string toFile)
    {
        string log = string.Format("fromFile={0},toFile={1}", fromFile, toFile);
        //EventLogger.Log(log);
        string arguments;

        //check the extension
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fromFile);
        if (ext == ".ulaw")
        {
            arguments = string.Format("-t ul {0} -c 1 -r 8000 {1}", fromFile, toFile);
        }
        else
        {
            arguments = string.Format(" {0} -c 1 -r 8000 {1}", fromFile, toFile);
        }
        //EventLogger.Log(arguments);
        string command = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\sox.exe";
        try
        {   
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            EventLogger.Error("GenerateSoundFile", e);
        }

        //check output file exists           
        if (!File.Exists(toFile))
        {
            //EventLogger.Error("No output sound file generated");

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;

        }

    }
```

Comment: EventLogger.Log not work in c# webforms !! can u explain me more

Comment: ohh, that's just my custom log class, replace with `Response.Write`

Comment: @user1283712 ok please approve my answer, if it solve it after trying

Comment: i try this function so i need convert file to PCM format howa argument input for Process

Comment: yeah i now but this function convert file wav to format ulow i try and i check format for output file, my probleme is can you convert file format ulow to PCM because i have thos exception "Additional information: Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files."

Comment: Can u send me a sample file

Comment: I need this format pcm unsigned 8 bit, 8000 HZ, 64 Kbps, mono in output can u help me please ?

Comment: yes I asked you to send me a sample file, you can share a link or email me `cybermeda@gmail.com`

Comment: Ok i send for you file.

Comment: how a new solution for this probleme @media Please

Comment: Yes i just need 10 min i went to grab a lunch sorry

Comment: mais bain tu connais l'anglais c sur tu parle le francais alors :p

Comment: Akhi, j'ai repondu a ton email

Comment: @user1283712 Im curious to know why `@jkgm777` gets the accepted answer when I spent hours helping you and you said that it worked ?